# jqGrid - How to modify form_editing construction?

Tags: jqgrid, form-editing

In the jqGrid documentation to form_editing, I see how the [form_editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) is constructed.

```
<form ...>
    <table>
        <tr id='tr_myfield'>  
          <td> Caption</td> 
          <td>edited element named, in colModel, as "myfield"</td> 
        </tr> ... 
    </table> 
</form>
```

Can I change this construction ?

It's necessary to me because I have too many columns to edit in my form and I want to display the form in most userfriendly way.
E.g when I have twenty columns to edit in my table. I have twenty rows in my form.
But I would obtain one row for two columns.
I understood that each rows are identifying by their index, so I can't just have two columns in the same row.
But if it's possible to faking it, be sure it's make me happy ^^
(e.g with two tables and a similar id or with form_editing parameters that I don't know ...)

PS : Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are `rowpos` and `colpos` properties of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions) which would be helpful for you.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm) demonstrate how you can change the standard editing form created by jqGrid to the following

[image]

If I understand correct your problem the usage of `rowpos` and `colpos` could be very helpful in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to customize the form, your best bet may be to create your own page and use a plugin such as [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to display your custom form. It will be more work since you cannot use the built-in form editing capabilities of jqGrid, but you will have complete control of the layout of the form.

Comment: It's a pity because I have considered this issue too late
Thanks for your answer