# how to split no of fields in add/edit form into leftside and right jqgrid when number of fields are more

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

[image]

Please check the table to understand requirement.Since number of fields are more i want 
   to shift few fields in right side of add form.

```
 **label field.**
 <table>
      <tr><td>label</td><td>input field</td></tr>
     </table>

  What i am expecting is in format:

  **label field label2 field2**

     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>label</td><td>field</td>
       <td>lablel2</td><td>field2</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

Could any one please assist me .
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The trick is the usage of `rowpos` and `colpos` properties of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions). In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852741/315935) you can find [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm) which demonstrate the technique.

If you have *really many columns* it could be not enough place on the screen even after the usage of multiple columns. In the case you can restrict the height of the Add/Edit form by usage of `dataheight` option. The disadvantage of the approach is the setting of *explicit value* of `height` CSS style on the data part of the editing form. The better way is setting of `max-height` which value you can calculate based on the screen resolution. For example you can make the changes inside of [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback

```js
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    $form.css({"max-height": 0.70*screen.height + "px"});
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MaxHeightOfEditingForm.htm) demonstrate the approach. In the same way you can set `max-width` too.

[image]

To show the results I used *both* `dataheight` and `beforeShowForm`. In the final solution you should remove the `dataheight` part of the settings.