# JQGrid - show additional columns in edit form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid table which has more than 30 columns. I think inline editing of these columns will not be user-friendly. So i would like to show several columns in grid mode, and show all columns only when user opens edit form of this row. Is this possible? Could not find this in tutorials.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **show** and not to edit the columns then the usage of [viewGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#viewgridrow) as the usage of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow). Moreover I would suggest you to consider to use [columnChooser](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#column_chooser) which allows user to hide/show columns of the grid or to change its order. For example you can display in the grid only subset of 30 rows, use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) to add View Details button (you need use `view: true` option) and use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) to add custom button with column chooser. You can additionally makes explicit call of `viewGridRow` inside of `ondblClickRow` callback. One need add the properties `editrules: {edithidden: true}` in the definition of all hidden columns which need be visible/editable in View/Edit/Add forms

The resulting grid can look like on [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/simpleNavGridWithViewAndColumnChooser.htm) or like here:

```js
$(function () {
  "use strict";
  var mydata = [
    { id: "10",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test1",  note: "note1",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "60",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "70",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "80",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "90",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
    { id: "110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
    { id: "120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
  ],
      $grid = $("#list"),
      initDateEdit = function (elem) {
        $(elem).datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
          autoSize: true,
          changeYear: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          showWeek: true
        });
      },
      initDateSearch = function (elem) {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(elem).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            autoSize: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            showWeek: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function () {
              if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                // call triggerToolbar only in case of searching toolbar
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $self[0].triggerToolbar();
                }, 100);
              }
            }
          });
        }, 100);
      },
      numberTemplate = {formatter: "number", align: "right", sorttype: "number",
                        editrules: {number: true, required: true},
                        searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "nu", "nn", "in", "ni"] }};

  $grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes", "Tax", "Amount", "Total"],
    colModel: [
      { name: "name", align: "center", editable: true, width: 65, editrules: {required: true} },
      { name: "invdate", width: 80, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
       formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" }, editable: true, datefmt: "d-M-Y",
       editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
       searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
      { name: "closed", width: 70, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "checkbox",
       edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"},
       stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" } },
      { name: "ship_via", width: 105, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "select",
       edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
       stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
      { name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea", hidden: true },
      { name: "tax", width: 52, editable: true, template: numberTemplate, hidden: true  },
      { name: "amount", width: 75, editable: true, template: numberTemplate, hidden: true },
      { name: "total", width: 60, template: numberTemplate }
    ],
    cmTemplate: {editable: true, editrules: {edithidden: true}},
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    sortname: "name",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    rownumbers: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    height: "auto",
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
      $(this).jqGrid("viewGridRow", rowid);
    }
  });
  $.extend($.jgrid.view, {
    caption: "View Record Details",
    recreateForm: true
  });
  $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false, view: true,
                                     viewtitle: "View details of selected row"
                                    });
  $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    caption: "",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
    title: "Choose Columns to display in the grid",
    onClickButton: function () {
      $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-jqgrid-hdiv { overflow-y: hidden; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/plugins/ui.multiselect-fixed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
  $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.6.0/plugins/jQuery.jqGrid.columnChooser.js"></script>

<table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

[image]

By the way you can use `rowpos` and `colpos` properties of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Acommon_rules#formoptions) to display information of Add/Edit/View forms in multicolumn form. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852741/315935) for the corresponding code example.

Comment: Thank you, Oleg! And what if i want to edit these rows in separate forms? For example show two columns (id & name) in grid and show other 28 columns in form. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Atver: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand your question. The demo which I posted contains the grid which displays not all columns. You can display two columns for example. I used `edit: false, view: true` options of `navGrid` and calls `viewGridRow` in `ondblClickRow`. You can remove `edit: false, view: true` option and replace `viewGridRow` to `editGridRow`. The properties `editrules: {edithidden: true}` will work with editing exactly like for viewing. The user will see Edit button which displays Edit form instead View form. Where you see any problem?

Comment: Now i get it) I have marked your answer as correct)