# Unable to display more than 8 rows while editing a row in jqgrid in edit form

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

I have followed JQGrid articles and help provided here and was able to display a table in JQGrid. I was able to do CRUD operations using edit form mode. I tried to repeat the same approach for another table but with more fields than the first table. In the second case, only 8 rows are displayed in edit form. The jqgrid colmodel goes till 10th row using rowpos and colpos.

I looked at [JQGrid - show additional columns in edit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404072/jqgrid-show-additional-columns-in-edit-form) but when i checked the example, it showed me 8 rows as per the example. Using dataheight, I was able to increase the height of the form but the additional rows still did not display.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Colmodel is as follows -

```
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', formatter: 'int', hidden: true /*, width: 100, align: 'right', frozen: true, editoptions: { defaultValue: 0 }*/
        }
        , { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 300, template: stringEdColTemplate
                , editoptions: { maxlength: 50, size: 40 }
                , formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *', rowpos: 1, colpos: 1 }, editrules: { required: true/*, custom:true, custom_func:formcheck*/ }
        }
        , { name: 'Code', index: 'Code', formatter: 'string', align: 'left', editable: true
            , editoptions: { maxlength: 20, size: 40 }
            , formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *', rowpos: 2, colpos: 1 }, editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: depotCodeLength }
        }
        , { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 150, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', editable: true
        , editoptions: { size: 40, email:true}, formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *', rowpos: 3, colpos: 1 }, edittype: 'text'
            , editrules: { required:true }
        }
        , { name: 'Location', index: 'Location', formatter: 'string', align: 'left', editable: true
            , editoptions: { maxlength: 9, size: 40 }
            , formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *', rowpos: 5, colpos: 1 }, editrules: { required: true }
        }
        , { name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', width: 75, formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox'
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 8, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editoptions: { value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
        , { name: 'Password', index: 'Password', width: 150, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', editable: true, hidden: true
        , editoptions: { size: 40 }
            , formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *', rowpos: 4, colpos: 1 }, edittype: 'text'
            , editrules: { required: true, edithidden:true }
        }
        , { name: 'Address1', index: 'Address1', width: 150, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', edittype: 'text'
                , editoptions: { maxlength: 25, size: 40 }, hidden:true
                , formoptions: { rowpos: 6, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden:true }
        }
        , { name: 'Address2', index: 'Address2', width: 150, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', edittype: 'text'
                , editoptions: { maxlength: 25, size: 40 }, hidden:true
                , formoptions: { rowpos: 7, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden:true }
        }
        , { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 150, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', edittype: 'text'
                , editoptions: { maxlength: 25, size: 40 }, hidden:true
                , formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden:true }
        }
        , { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', width: 200, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *', rowpos: 2, colpos: 2 }
            , hidden:true, editable: true
                , edittype: 'select', editrules: { required: true }
                , editoptions: countryOptions
        }
        , { name: 'CountryCode', index: 'CountryCode', width: 50, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', hidden: true }
        , { name: 'Zip', index: 'Zip', width: 50, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', edittype: 'text'
            , editoptions: { maxlength: 25, size: 40 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 2 }, editable: true
            , editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true
        }
        , { name: 'HomePhone', index: 'HomePhone', width: 50, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', edittype: 'text'
            , editoptions: { maxlength: 25, size: 40 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 2 }, editable: true
            , editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true
        }
        , { name: 'WorkPhone', index: 'WorkPhone', width: 50, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', edittype: 'text'
            , editoptions: { maxlength: 25, size: 40 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 5, colpos: 2 }, editable: true
            , editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true
        }
        , { name: 'Mobile', index: 'Mobile', width: 50, formatter: 'string', align: 'left', edittype: 'text'
            , editoptions: { maxlength: 25, size: 40 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 6, colpos: 2 }, editable: true
            , editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidden: true
        }
        , { name: 'Path', index: 'Path', align: 'right', formatter: 'string', editable: true, hidden: true }
        , { name: 'Day1', index: 'Day1', width: 75, , formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', hidden:true
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 8, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editoptions: { edithidden:true, value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
         , { name: 'Day2', index: 'Day2', width: 75, , formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', hidden: true
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 9, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editoptions: { edithidden:true, value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
          , { name: 'Day3', index: 'Day3', width: 75, , formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', hidden: true
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 9, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editoptions: { edithidden:true, value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
        , { name: 'Day4', index: 'Day4', width: 75, , formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', hidden: true
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 10, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editoptions: { edithidden:true, value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
         , { name: 'Day5', index: 'Day5', width: 75, , formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', hidden: true
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 10, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editoptions: { edithidden:true, value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
         , { name: 'Day6', index: 'Day6', width: 75, , formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', hidden: true
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 11, colpos: 1 }, editable: true, editoptions: { edithidden:true, value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
         , { name: 'Day7', index: 'Day7', width: 75, , formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', hidden: true
        , formoptions: { rowpos: 11, colpos: 2 }, editable: true, editoptions: { edithidden:true, value: 'Yes:No', defaultValue: 'Yes' }
        }
      ]
```

Found the answer in [jQgrid show hidden column in form view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645787/jqgrid-show-hidden-column-in-form-view)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first to test without using rowpos and colpos. If this shows the correct number of columns, you will maybe need to look at your code again for some errors.

Kind Regards