# place two textbox side by side in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

My Add/Edit form is having too many fields in jqgrid dialog. So is there any way to place the two text box side by side in html

for eg :

```
            Name: textbox      Age : textbox

            Gender : dropdown  Email: textbox
```

Please help me out with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowpos` and `colpos` of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions) to implement multicolumn form. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm) created for [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852741/315935). It display the edit form like on the picture below:

[image]